# Flask app with Apache proxy + Gunicorn not working on HTTPS

Tags: apache, flask, ssl, gunicorn, mod-proxy

**Updates in the bottom, I kind of solved it but not sure if the solution is a correct one.**

---

I have Apache running on CentOS with a proxy to localhost port 8080 where I have Flask app running using Gunicorn. This setup works on Apache port 80 (HTTP) and I can connect to it using my domain http://example.com with a browser but now I have tried to setup SSL/HTTPS and it just doesn't work.

Navigating to https://example.com tries to load the page for a while (like 30ish seconds) and then it shows 502 error page:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Apache error log:

```
[proxy_http:error] [pid 30209] (103)Software caused connection abort: [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60556] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8080
[proxy:error] [pid 30209] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:60556] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /
```

Gunicorn error log (first 7 lines are from Gunicorn startup, no idea why this info is in error log, last 3 lines are when the HTTPS request returns 502 error):

```
[29478] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (29478)
[29478] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[29480] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29480
[29481] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29481
[29482] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29482
[29483] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29483
[29484] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29484
[29478] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:29480)
[29480] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29480)
[29554] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29554
```

Apache config which is working for HTTP (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`):

```
Listen 80

#other default config values here

<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Apache config which is not working for HTTPS (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`):

```
Listen 443 https

#other default config values here

<VirtualHost *:443>

#other default config values here too

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/cert.key

SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

If I remove/comment the `SSLProxyEngine`, `ProxyPass` amd `ProxyPassReverse` lines and restart Apache I get the default Apache welcome page and HTTPS works just fine so clearly the problem is in the Proxy somehow?

The flask app is started with Gunicorn by:

`gunicorn --config gunicorn_config.py app:app`

gunicorn_config.py:

```
workers = 5
bind = '127.0.0.1:8080'
umask = 0o007
reload = True
accesslog = 'log_gunicorn_access.txt'
errorlog = 'log_gunicorn_error.txt'
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
    def hello_world():  
        return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

And once again, this works when navigating to my domain using HTTP but doesn't work when using HTTPS.

Any help?

---

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get another error. Now navigating to https://example.com loads instantly and shows 500 error page:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server
```

Apache error log:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 32385] (502)Unknown error 502: [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50932] AH01084: pass request body failed to [::1]:8080 (localhost)
[proxy:error] [pid 32385] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50932] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[proxy_http:error] [pid 32385] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50932] AH01097: pass request body failed to [::1]:8080 (localhost) from xx.xxx.xxx.xxx ()
```

No more any errors in Gunicorn error log.

I added these two lines to gunicorn_config.py:

```
keyfile = '/etc/pki/tls/private/cert.key'
certfile = '/etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.pem'
```

and made sure both files are accessible by the user running Gunicorn (chmod o+r cert.key/pem).

No idea if I was supposed to change it like this as I thought the traffic should go like: client --https--> Apache and then Apache --http--> Gunicorn.

Also HTTP (http://example.com) no longer works and gives the previous 502 error page but I guess running Gunicorn with the cert configs doesn't allow HTTP anymore and would need to run the app twice with different configs).

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I added more Apache logging by adding this line to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` inside virtual host:

`LogLevel info`

And now I got additional info in Apache error log:

```
[ssl:info] [pid 3808] [remote 127.0.0.1:8080] AH02411: SSL Proxy: Peer certificate does not match for hostname localhost
```

Then I added new line to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` inside virtual host:

`SSLProxyCheckPeerName off`

And now I got another Apache error:

```
[ssl:info] [pid 3999] [remote 127.0.0.1:8080] AH02005: SSL Proxy: Peer certificate CN mismatch: Certificate CN: example.com Requested hostname: localhost
```

Added new line to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` inside virtual host:

`SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off`

Aaaand now navigating to https://example.com correctly works and I get "Hello world" back from the app!

Now I guess my question needs update as well: **Is it bad practice, wrong or insecure to use `SSLProxyCheckPeerName off` and `SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off` in this context?** Or is there a better way as I don't think there's a way to order an official SSL certificate on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

and

```
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8080/
```

(note the 1 letter difference).

Your `localhost:8080` will serve *either* http *or* https. Based on your description (and common expectations) it's serving http. If you proxy even your :443 virtual host to http, it'll work *better*.

You might run into more issues, as the proxied application doesn't really know that it's *actually* served through https, but that's a different beast than this question.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, yes I wanted to only serve client -> Apache over https and not deal with it with internal Apache --> Gunicorn/Flask. Don't think the app cares about whether it's served over http/https. Thank you!

Comment: well - some apps do care - if only to be able to generate links that use the same protocol. Or to refuse accepting any credentials unencrypted. Lucky (on some scale) if you don't run into this. On the other hand, this would catch a whole class of errors.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I run into any problems! Do you happen to know any links/resources where that issue is explained more thorougly, I'm interested in learning more about it and possible ways to solve it.